# haw to validate values in set methods?

Tags: java, oop

I recently began to learn object oriented programming and i have a question.
for example i am doing a class called student and i have his ID so i am going to write a setID method

```
  public int setID(idval)
   {if(idval>=0 &&idval<=100) 
        ID=idval;
    else system.out.print("Invalid ID");
   }
```

My question is haw do i need to ask the user to enter another id because the first one was invalid.
haw the user can try again another id if the first was invalid ??

Comment: This might be beyond your scope but you should separate the actual setter from the part of your code that interacts with the user. And the one that interacts with the user would have a loop waiting for correct input.

Comment: Try calling say validate method where you validate input rather than validating in setter.

Comment: setID() should throw an IllegalArgumentException, not display an error message. The actual validation and interaction with the user shouldn't be done in Student.

Comment: Think about your API. You should indicate errors in the code to the _code_ not the end _end user_. Throwing an exception is easily detectable; printing to the output is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following. This separates the code into individual methods. This is how you should create your methods. They should do s specific thing. This also uses recursion, which is when a method calls itself till a condition is met.

```
private int idval = 0;

public int getIdval() {
    return idval;
}

public void setIdval(int idval) {
    this.idval = idval;
}

private boolean isValidId(int idValue){
    if(idValue >= 0 && idValue <= 100){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public void userId(){

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
    int id = reader.nextInt();

    if(isValidId(id)){
        setIdval(id);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid ID")
        userId();
    }

    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: First, this allows invalid values to be set though incorrect use of the API - this is an ugly kludge. Second, the `isValidId` method should be `return idValue >= 0 && idValue <= 100`. This is both bad code and incorrect API design.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to let the user know in some way that they have passed in a bad value.

There's no one-size-fits-all approach to this but throwing an `Exception` and documenting your expectations ([using JavaDoc](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Farticles%2Fjava%2Findex-137868.html&ei=JLeiVNG_DsOdNuGThLgH&usg=AFQjCNE0rKNsA42aESRiqSOEuh-SXpuzbA&sig2=zuPKQAedURxumEH5MXDC7Q&bvm=bv.82001339,d.eXY&cad=rja)) are two good approaches.

Also, it isn't idiomatic Java for setters to return values.

If I were to rewrite (and reformat!) your code, I would do this:

```
/**
 * Set the ID 
 * @param idval An integer between 0 and 100, inclusive.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if ID is out of range.
 **/
public void setID(int idval) {
    if(idval >= 0 && idval <= 100) {
       ID = idval;
    } else {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be between 0 and 100");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would reverse the `if` - it makes more sense.

Comment: @BorisTheSpider Yeah, I probably would too. I was trying not to stray too far from the original though. Feel free to edit it if you feel strongly otherwise! :) (thanks for the format edit just now)

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/) can be a nice starting point for validating POJOs (beans). It moves the bean validation code away from the POJOs and to an external validator.

If you are working inside a Java EE container or if you are using e.g. Spring you can enable bean validation quite simply and use the annotations that are available.

Note that this validation is typically placed on the field or the getter - **not the setter**.

Some of the annotations are:

- `@NotNull`
- `@Null`
- `@Max`
- `@Min`
- `@AssertFalse`
- `@Size`

An example can be the `@NotNull` annotation which can be used like this:

```
@NotNull
private String name;
```

When the object is validated the validator checks that the property isn't null. Simple as that ;)

If you want to programmatically do validation on the setter I suggest that you document what is expected in either the JavaDoc or as a unit test that is shared by all developers (the latter alternative is only an option for *internal* projects).

Then I suggest that you use some kind of assertion utility to avoid code clutter. E.g. Spring Framework uses the `Assert` class.

```
/**
 * Sets foo, does not accept null values.
 * @param foo Must not be null.
 */
public void setFoo(String foo) {
    Assert.notNull(foo, "Foo must not be null");
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

Some resources on the subject of validation:

- [Spring Validation - validation when using Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)
- [Bean Validation using Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)
- [JSR 303 (The Bean Validation specification)](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/)
- [Java EE 6 - Bean Validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html)

Comment: Me personally, I prefer "fail fast". Meaning I validate my values in the setter methods and need no cluttering annotations that lazily validate the values when flushing. That is the only way I can guarantee that the in-memory version of my entity is as clean as can be. Also, failing fast mean that client code can expect and handle exceptions where they really originate from.

Comment: @MartinAndersson - agreed. I tend to design most objects immutable and then you typically get a *fail fast* behaviour.

Comment: The `Assert` you use, doesn't that throw `AssertionError`?  If so, then it's not even an exception type. Usually, I don't do NPE checks. If and when a value must be dereferenced, then the code will inevitably crash with a NPE - so problem solved. In a setter method, I usually do `Objects.requireNonNull(val, "val is null")`.

Comment: @MartinAndersson - The assert method throws `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: Which group/artifact/package?

Comment: @MartinAndersson - The example illustrates usage of  `org.springframework.util.Assert` class from `spring-core` and is obviously only a valid option if Spring Framework is used in the project (groupId: org.springframework, artifactId: spring-core).

Comment: oh awesome. I was just wondering where it came from =) Thanx mate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple workable example, hope it might be helpful.

```
public class Student {
private long Id;

public long getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    if (id >= 0 && id <= 100) {
        this.Id = id;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student = new Student();
    Console console = System.console();
    String input = null;
    System.out.println("Input a valid student id");
    while ((input = console.readLine()) != null) {
        try {
            input = input.replaceAll("^\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
            if (input.length() > 0) {
                student.setId(Long.valueOf(input));
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Input a valid student id");
                continue;
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Input a valid student id");
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Student id is " + student.getId());
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The correct way is applying the separation of responsibility principle. Leaves that validation in other place like the service layer or the GUI layer.

Comment: No. This is an incorrect generalisation. Just look at the [Java Validation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html). If an object has invariants, it should be **its** responsibility to ensure they hold.

Comment: @Boris the Spider I understand your point. Let me try explain what is the mine. You can have the same bussines objects to all the softwares in the company but for each one the bussines object have a different behaviours. Applying those kinds of validation directly over the bussines object does not permit re-use the bussines object model.